# Angularjs xeditable not showing value in input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular-xeditable to update individual values on a view. Additionally, I am retrieving those values from a remote server, here is snippet:

```
$http.get('api/get-solution').success(function (data) {

        $scope.goalSoluton   = data['goal_planning_data'];

    });
```

And this is what has been return from the remote server:

```
{age:"26" retirement:"0"}
```

In my HTML view I see that the object property value of age (which is 26) is displayed, Here is a snippet:

```
<a href="#"  editable-text="goalSolution.age" onaftersave="update()">{{goalSoluton.age}}</a>
```

But when I had clicked to edit that input field the value of 26 does not show up. Also, when I even entered a value in the input field and pressed the update button, the age property of the object did not update. Here is a snippet of the function:

```
    $scope.update = function () {
       console.log($scope.goalSoluton);
};
```

What am I doing wrong and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You try to href get empty.   . we used that. Maybe.

Comment: This should be a comment Not a full answer

Comment: I do not understand, could you give an example

Comment: <a href editable-text="goalSolution.age" onaftersave="update()">{{goalSoluton.age}}</a> you try it.

Comment: $scope.update = function () {
       console.log($scope.goalSoluton.age);
};